# Convert a text into a dictionary

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

I want to covert a .txt file into a dictionary.
the file contains two columns of letters:
a s
d f
g h
t y
u i
y u
I tried the following code:

```
f=open('file.txt')
for line in f:
   letters = line.split() #convert them into a list
   c=tuple(letters) #convert the list to a tuple
   d=dict((y, x) for x, y in c)
print d
```

I want to convert all the lettes to a tuple then convert it to a dictionary..
{'first letter':'second letter'}
but it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#43>", line 4, in <module> d= {y:x for x,y in tpl}
File "<pyshell#43>", line 4, in <dictcomp> d= {y:x for x,y in tpl}
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

How to fix this?
I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: You only show one column of letters. Make sure that on the line `c=...`, `c` is really getting two values.

Comment: forget about the last two lines.. when I write print c I get all letters into tuples, how can I put these tuples into a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file.txt

```
a s
d f
g h
t y
u i
y u
```

code

```
with open ('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    data = dict([x.split() for x in f.read().splitlines()])
print data
#{'a': 's', 'd': 'f', 'g': 'h', 'u': 'i', 't': 'y', 'y': 'u'}
```